# How can I modify the following Prolog program

Tags: prolog

I have written the following program to compute all pairs of members in a list. Here is my code:

```
select_pair(X, Y, [X|[Y|T]], T).
select_pair(X, Y, [Head|[X|[Y|T]]], [Head|Rest]) :- select_pair(X, Y, T, Rest).
```

I am supposed to call my code with this 3-member list only:

```
select pair(X, Y, [1,2,3], Zs).
```

But this doesn't generate all possible combinations. It only generates

```
X = 1, Y = 2, Zs = [3]
```

and it is supposed to generate this, but it does not:

```
X = 1, Y = 2, Zs = [3] ;
X = 1, Y = 3, Zs = [2] ;
X = 2, Y = 1, Zs = [3] ;
X = 2, Y = 3, Zs = [1] ;
X = 3, Y = 1, Zs = [2] ;
X = 3, Y = 2, Zs = [3]
```

So, how can I modify this code to generate all possible pairs of members of the list [1, 2, 3]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use procedure `select/3`:

```
select_pair(X, Y, List, Rest):-
  select(X, List, MList),
  select(Y, MList, Rest).
```

The first select would remove the first element from List into X and put the rest of the list in MList.

Then the second select would get you the second element and the Rest.

Comment: Excellent. never mind my prev. comment. I just saw how you modified select/3. Works like a charm. Thanks